# Oracle SQL How to find missing value for different users

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 tables

One table with questions

```
ID Description
== ===========
1  Some Question
2  Some Question
3  Some Question
4  Some Question
```

And an other one with the awsers to each question of every users

```
ID_USER ID_QUESTION ANSWER
======= =========== =========
1       2           a
1       1           b
1       3           d
2       1           e
2       4           a
3       4           c
3       2           a
```

As you can see it is possible that a user does not answer a question and this is my problem

I am currently trying to find wich answer a user did not answer to.

I'd like to have something like this

```
ID_USER ID_MISSING_QUESTION
======= ===================
1       4
2       3
2       2
3       1
3       3
```

I can easly find the missing questions for a single user but i can't do that for every user since they are quite numerous.

Thanks Ayoye

Comment: How are you getting (what SQL) that first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and Dirty:

```
SELECT TB_USER.ID, TB_QUESTION.ID AS "Q_ID" FROM TB_USER, TB_QUESTION
minus
SELECT ID_USER, ID_QUESTION FROM tb_answer
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7bc0d/16/0)

Answer (score 0):

You should post the SQL statement(s) you tried, before expecting a full answer, else someone might think you want let others write all the code for you...

Nevertheless, instead of plain JOIN, use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` resp. `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, depending on table ordering in your SQL statement (which you did not post yet), and filter with `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
    u.id_user,
    q.id_question
FROM
    questions q
CROSS JOIN users u
LEFT JOIN answers a ON (a.id_question = q.id_question and a.id_user = u.id_user)
WHERE
    a.answer IS NULL
```

First You shoyul create set of every question for every user, and then try to join in with Your answers. And then filer out all results that have found answers. :)